# Continuous variable Treatment Group in DID Regression

Tags: regression, difference-in-difference, treatment-effect

I am struggling to understand how to interpret the treatment and control group in the following case of DID regression. We need to estimate the causal effect of brick kilns on downwind PM2.5 monitor readings. Using the wind direction we identified the number of brick kilns that are upwind to monitor on a given day. Also brick production is a seasonal activity and operates only for 5 months in a year. We run the following equation:

PM2.5 = β0 + β1 Kilnsd + β2 Seasond+ β3  Kilnsd × Seasond + θXd + ed

where Kilnsd= no of kilns upwind to monitor identified on a particular day

```
  season= dummy variable for kilns off and on

 Xd = vector of meteorological controls

 Kilnsd × Seasond= interaction term  between the number of upwind kilns and the brick season
```

The author of the paper states that we  measure whether changes in pollution between the brick-producing season (approximately November to March) and the nonproducing season (the rest of the year) were larger on days when the air pollution monitor was downwind from more kilns as compared to days when the air pollution monitor was downwind from fewer kilns after controlling for other factors.

**In this case, instead of binary treatment variable, we have continuous values. I  am not able to distinguish between what is treatment group and what is controlled?**

Comment: What do you mean by interpret? Are you having trouble interpreting the coefficient values? Or, do you mean you’re having trouble discriminating between treatment/control groups?

Comment: I am having trouble in discriminating between treatment/control group